# Does Mimic spawn in hard mode only?

Tags: terraria

They did spawn on pre-hard mode before on my phone, but on my desktop version they are not showing up. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Mimics only naturally spawn in hard mode. The only way for them to appear before hard mode is by activating a Chest Statue using wire.

Do note that when spawned by the statue, they will drop no items at all.

Comment: I better get a chest statue now

Comment: yeah i need one too

Comment: There's not much point guys, they only provide banners...

Comment: yeah i know im making an afk farm and banners provide a huge buff